# PostgreSQL Select * faster than selecting columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I'm writing a query in Postgres and noticed a significant drop in performance when specifying which columns to select.
The two queries I'm comparing are basically:

- **A**:

```
select 
*
from rate r 
left join transportmode tm on r.mode_id = tm.id
left join tarif trf on r.tarif_id = trf.id
left join rate_clients rc on r.id=rc.rate_id 
left join client c on c.id = rc.client_id
where c.active = 1;
```

- **B**:

```
select 
r.durationfrom as "RATE START DATE",
r.durationto as "RATE END DATE",
tm."name" as "MODE",
trf.reference as "Contract Number",
c.name as "Controlling Customer"
from rate r 
left join transportmode tm on r.mode_id = tm.id
left join tarif trf on r.tarif_id = trf.id
left join rate_clients rc on r.id=rc.rate_id 
left join client c on c.id = rc.client_id
where c.active = 1;
```

**A** takes around a few seconds while **B** can take up to 2 minutes.

I ran **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** on both queries and below is the result:

- **A**:

```
Gather  (cost=69460.51..24027323.02 rows=6476258 width=3544) (actual time=411.698..140888.045 rows=8250182 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=14169264 read=98625, temp read=185212 written=185168
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=68460.51..23378697.22 rows=2698441 width=3544) (actual time=400.162..128621.857 rows=2750061 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (r.mode_id = tm.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=41102999 read=277273, temp read=539228 written=539096
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=68459.44..23352611.22 rows=2698441 width=2992) (actual time=400.083..126775.237 rows=2750061 loops=3)
              Hash Cond: (r.tarif_id = trf.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=41102996 read=277273, temp read=539228 written=539096
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=48843.28..21664418.39 rows=2698441 width=2435) (actual time=255.677..118794.352 rows=2750061 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=41088452 read=277273, temp read=45942 written=45852
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=48842.71..259302.65 rows=2698441 width=836) (actual time=251.361..3392.426 rows=2750061 loops=3)
                          Hash Cond: (rc.client_id = c.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=90532, temp read=45942 written=45852
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rate_clients rc  (cost=0.00..93266.60 rows=3977460 width=13) (actual time=0.016..361.609 rows=3147527 loops=3)
                                Buffers: shared hit=53492
                          ->  Hash  (cost=17311.47..17311.47 rows=271779 width=823) (actual time=250.956..250.956 rows=274778 loops=3)
                                Buckets: 32768  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 4198kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=36912, temp written=21129
                                ->  Seq Scan on client c  (cost=0.00..17311.47 rows=271779 width=823) (actual time=0.042..134.485 rows=274778 loops=3)
                                      Filter: (active = '1'::numeric)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 125798
                                      Buffers: shared hit=36912
                    ->  Index Scan using ratepk on rate r  (cost=0.57..7.93 rows=1 width=1599) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=8250182)
                          Index Cond: (id = rc.rate_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=40997920 read=277273
              ->  Hash  (cost=6420.74..6420.74 rows=157474 width=557) (actual time=92.684..92.684 rows=156802 loops=3)
                    Buckets: 32768  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 4890kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=14538, temp written=11460
                    ->  Seq Scan on tarif trf  (cost=0.00..6420.74 rows=157474 width=557) (actual time=0.032..28.018 rows=156802 loops=3)
                          Buffers: shared hit=14538
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.03..1.03 rows=3 width=552) (actual time=0.050..0.050 rows=3 loops=3)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              Buffers: shared hit=3
              ->  Seq Scan on transportmode tm  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=552) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=3 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning time: 9.650 ms
Execution time: 141261.043 ms
```

- **B**:

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=9228694.06..10772572.88 rows=6476258 width=115) (actual time=107381.499..136924.845 rows=8250182 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (r.tarif_id = trf.id)
  Buffers: shared hit=7240 read=6005956 dirtied=7302 written=3, temp read=675690 written=674666
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=9220304.89..10682421.32 rows=6476258 width=65) (actual time=107255.939..134586.629 rows=8250182 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (r.mode_id = tm.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=7229 read=6001121 dirtied=7290 written=3, temp read=675690 written=674666
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=9220303.83..10619816.43 rows=6476258 width=66) (actual time=107255.903..132566.930 rows=8250182 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (rc.rate_id = r.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=7228 read=6001121 dirtied=7290 written=3, temp read=675690 written=674666
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=23097.71..388176.55 rows=6476258 width=47) (actual time=323.454..4409.005 rows=8250182 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (rc.client_id = c.id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=32 read=65767 dirtied=23, temp read=13476 written=13474
                    ->  Seq Scan on rate_clients rc  (cost=0.00..148951.03 rows=9545903 width=13) (actual time=1.651..1023.910 rows=9442580 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=10 read=53482 dirtied=10
                    ->  Hash  (cost=17311.47..17311.47 rows=271779 width=46) (actual time=320.752..320.752 rows=274778 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 262144  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 12633kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=19 read=12285 dirtied=13, temp written=1115
                          ->  Seq Scan on client c  (cost=0.00..17311.47 rows=271779 width=46) (actual time=0.019..241.957 rows=274778 loops=1)
                                Filter: (active = '1'::numeric)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 125798
                                Buffers: shared hit=19 read=12285 dirtied=13
              ->  Hash  (cost=7016250.94..7016250.94 rows=107370094 width=33) (actual time=106913.359..106913.359 rows=91327549 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 262144  Batches: 512  Memory Usage: 13564kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=7196 read=5935354 dirtied=7267 written=3, temp written=601510
                    ->  Seq Scan on rate r  (cost=0.00..7016250.94 rows=107370094 width=33) (actual time=1.395..82436.742 rows=91327549 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=7196 read=5935354 dirtied=7267 written=3
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.03..1.03 rows=3 width=9) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=3 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              Buffers: shared hit=1
              ->  Seq Scan on transportmode tm  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=9) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Hash  (cost=6420.74..6420.74 rows=157474 width=61) (actual time=124.699..124.699 rows=156802 loops=1)
        Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16525kB
        Buffers: shared hit=11 read=4835 dirtied=12
        ->  Seq Scan on tarif trf  (cost=0.00..6420.74 rows=157474 width=61) (actual time=0.009..83.061 rows=156802 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=11 read=4835 dirtied=12
Planning time: 28.417 ms
Execution time: 137233.834 ms
```

It seems as soon as I specify which columns to get it changes the plan to use Seq Scan instead of Index Scan. I am by no means an expert in analyzing queries and was hoping someone could explain what's happening and how I can get **B** to run faster.

Comment: We need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN on client is rather strange as it turns into an INNER JOIN because of the WHERE condition. And you're sure you want to collect 6.5 million records?

Comment: What you show is just EXPLAIN, not EXPLAIN ANALYZE.